# Line: 35, ERR_MSG: XML parsing: line 1, character 1088, illegal qualified name character

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing, for-xml-path

How to replace `<` symbol from XML? I need to understand the concept like we replace `&` with `&amp;` in xml.

For example:

```
Declare @xml xml,@xmlType nvarchar(max)

select @xmlType = '<root><stuff><test>something < this will error</test></stuff</root>'

select @xml = REPLACE(@xmlType, '<', '&lt;') 

select @xml
```

If i do it like this, then answer will be

```
'&lt;root&gt;&lt;stuff&gt;&lt;test&gt;something &lt; this will error&lt;/test&gt;&lt;/stuff&lt;/root&gt;'....
```

But I need answer like

```
<root><stuff><test>something &lt; this will error</test></stuff></root>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue through SQL query/stored procedure/T-SQL??

How to solve this issue:

> Line: 35, ERR_MSG: XML parsing: line 1, character 1088, illegal qualified name character

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is actual answer: &lt;root&gt; &lt;stuff&gt; &lt;test&gt;something &lt; this will error&lt;/test&gt; &lt;/stuff&gt; &lt;/root&gt; 

and this is expected answer: <root><stuff><test>something &lt; this will error</test></stuff></root>

Comment: Your trying to create XML from something that is not XML, the `<` invalidates it.  The place to fix this is higher up, wherever that string comes from.

Comment: I have a XML file which have special characters like &,',<,>,". I am extracting elements from XML usin T-SQL, but some tag values hold special characters. 

Like:

<root> 
<Name1>abc</Name1> 
<Name2>c&de</Name2>
<Name3>a<bc</Name3>
</root>

while reading itself from XML db it is throwing exception. 
Ex: Line: 35, ERR_MSG: XML parsing: line 1, character 1088, illegal qualified name character. If i validate correct parsing then after extraction value should be abc,c&de,a<bc. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: An XML file that has elements containing values like `<` and `&` is not XML, its just text that looks like XML - because both of those characters invalidate XML. You will have significant difficulties trying to parse it with anything.

Comment: Ya Alex i agree, it is ntext looks like xml, but my main purpose it to extract data from xml using t-sql. but how to do it if this file holds invalid characters?? Can we extract data from xml via t-sql even though it hold invalid characters??

Comment: If your text is just as you put it there, it's almost impossible to suggest something (unless *do it by hand* ). There might be a chance if you know more about your XML. How is this XML generated? Is this under your control? Is this a one-time-issue or something you need to automate?  Do you know all XML-tags which might occur within  this text?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to make sure there is a space between in ' < ' or some other qualifier to not pickup the other '<'.

```
Declare
     @xml xml
    ,@xmlType nvarchar(max)

SET @xmlType = '<root><stuff><test>something < this will error</test></stuff></root>'

SET @xmlType = REPLACE(@xmlType, ' < ', ' &lt; ')

SET @xml = CAST(@xmlType AS XML)

SELECT @xml
```

Comment: Thanks Arleigh Reyna for the reply, but in XML there is no space after '<', that is main concern. But i am advised to remove it manually as we don't have option. Thanks once again.